# R: How to generate this conditional binomial random variable?

Tags: r

I want to generate `Xi` from the following model. I know how to generate data from a `binomial distribution`, what I can do is as follow, but how can I generate data at the same time satisfy the condition that `Y = 1` or `Y =-1`?

```
set.seed(100)
n1<-50
n2<-50
p1<- 0.4
p2<- 0.3

y <- c(rep(1,50),rep(-1,50))
xi1<- c(rbinom(n1,1,p1), rbinom(n2,1,p2))
```

[image]

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi Thank you, but could you add some explanation? I don't see where to indicate "given Y =1 or -1".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `rbinom()` is vectorized, we can do

```
n <- ifelse(y == 1, n1, n2)
p <- ifelse(y == 1, p1, p2)
rbinom(n, 1, p)
```

You'd better read `?rbinom` closely.